# Extract portion of a text from a web page

Tags: javascript, python

Im trying to generate a list of getfile.do strings for a particular type of report - a "technical" report. The problem is that the report "type" is tagged at the end of the string, so the code should read the string and if the report tag checks out it should go back and extract the getfile.do (action).

Here is a sample from the source webpage (WWW.SEDAR.COM) (there is a lot of unwanted stuff, but the below is one i do want. So if we read "Technical Report" in the code below, I want to extract the action information (so I can use it to download the document). The problem is that many of the page links are not relevant.

FORM name="form1512323126173" action="/**GetFile.do lang=EN&docClass=24&issuerNo=00021020&issuerType=03&projectNo=02627564&d cId=4117642**" method="post" target="AcceptTermsOfUse"P HREF="javascript:submitFiling(document.form1512323126173,'AcceptTermsOf use');"title="&docClass=24&issuerNo=00021020&issuerType=03&projectNo=026 7564&docId=4117642"onmouseover="window.status='&docClass=24&issuerNo=000 1020&issuerType=03&projectNo=02627564&docId=4117642';return true;"onmouseout="window.status='';return true;">**Technical report (NI 43101)**

Below is an example, (on the same page) that Im not interested in:

FORM name="form1512323126172" action="/GetFile.do lang=EN&docClass=24&issuerNo=00021020&issuerType=03&projectNo=02627564&d cId=4117645" method="post" target="AcceptTermsOfUse"PA HREF="javascript:submitFiling(document.form1512323126172,'AcceptTermsOfU e');"title="&docClass=24&issuerNo=00021020&issuerType=03&projectNo=02627 64&docId=4117645"onmouseover="window.status='&docClass=24&issuerNo=00021020&issuerType=03&projectNo=02627564&docId=4117645';return true;" onmouseout="window.status='';return true;">Consent of qualified person(NI 43-101)

So in conclusion from a web page scrape of the above, I would hope to see the output as follow:

**action="/GetFile.do lang=EN&docClass=24&issuerNo=00021020&issuerType=03&p ojectNo=02627564&d cId=4117642**

Comment: have you tried anything? Let us know a problem you have in your approach instead. It seems like you are hoping someone will just do the work for you.

Comment: happy to do the work, just need a steer in the right direction (as a newbie)  -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library of python with [Beautifulsoap](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Install 3rd party libraries by following commands::

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
pip install requests
```